# how can i convert a tuple into string

Tags: python, robotframework

Using [DataBaseLibrary](http://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/api/0.5/DatabaseLibrary.html#Connect%20To%20Database) for Robot Framework i get list of tuples

```
@{recordList}    Query    select * from employee
```

How can i convert this into string? I want to write this to a file.

When i try FOR ${ELEMENT} in @{recordList}

```
str{$ELEMENT}
```

If the value in tuple is "correct_text" it prints "str(correct_text)" into file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in library for robot contains the keyword [Catenate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Catenate), which can be used convert a list or tuple to a string. By default it will place a space between each item, but you can specify a different character if you wish.

```
| | ${str}= | Catenate | @{recordList} | 
| | Append to file | /tmp/junk.txt | ${str}
```